# track data object that is behind tableview cell & extending PFTableViewCell

Tags: ios7, parse-platform

I am feeding a PFQueryTableViewController as per normal. All is good. Needing to pass selected objects to the next view controller. Easy enough to get selected rows via indexpaths. Here it gets seemingly illogical. I see no examples, no talk, nil on storage of the object that was used to setup the cell in the first place. Makes little sense to re-hit the db to grab via Id's. If the tag was an object we could store there, but it is not.

So, i code a category using Associative Reference, seen below, but wondered if i missed the boat somehow and there is a built-in way to manage this. Given parse augmented cellForRowAtIndexPath with an object param, surely the thought crossed their minds?

Is there a better way to store a cell's data object?

```
// .h
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface PFTableViewCell (PFObject)

@property (nonatomic, copy) PFObject *cellPFObject;

// .m
#import "PFTableViewCell+PFObject.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

NSString * const kEAPFObjectKey = @"kEAPFObjectKey";

@implementation PFTableViewCell (PFObject)

- (void)setCellPFObject:(PFObject *)cellObject
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void *)(kEAPFObjectKey), cellObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);

}

- (PFObject *)cellPFObject
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void *)(kEAPFObjectKey));
}
```

Comment: I am really not sure if I understand your question correctly, but why don't you just use the method `-(PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` ?

Comment: thanks Knshn.. I will revisit my segue, as i am aware of this you post. I was working on passing all the objects of the selected rows and was running into issues. The objectsAtIndexPaths was seemingly not giving me what was required. I will post back shortly.